# Retrying a for loop?

Tags: java, try-catch

Is it possible to use a for lop to set a condition of an object. And if that condition does not pass a test (if statement), the condition is changed until it does pass the test? Here is my pseudo code attempt, but i doubt it will work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i){
    myArray.get(i).position = random Position
    if(myArray.get(i).position == allowed position){
       //Success!
   }else{
      //re-attempt to change position until it meets criteria
   }
}
```

Please dont hate, i just started Java. And english is not my native language

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `while` loop:

```
myArray.get(i).position = random Position

while (myArray.get(i).position != 100) {
    myArray.get(i).position = random Position
}
// Success!
```

Comment: So if i have a lot of objects to check through, is this still efficient? If my Array contains 200 objects?

Comment: @TastyLemons: Hell no! It's never efficient. If you want to set the position to 100, set it to 100. Don't flail wildly until you happen to land on 100 by sheer luck.

Comment: @TastyLemons Why you would like to assign to position a random value, if you will only reach `//Success` when the random value is 100?

Comment: If possible, try using an ordered set instead of an array. That way, you won't need to check over all the 200 objects.

Comment: Well. I have made a tree generator, and i want to randomize the position of each tree. BUt only within a certain position. And i want to check, if it is outside of that position, retry. So that all of my trees are created only where i want them.

Comment: @TastyLemons: Then generate a random position within the range you need.

Comment: The range isnt a square shape, i am drawing an image with Color RGB(0,255,0) and im loading that image and going through each pixel. If pixel is green, trees can spawn there. So its any shape

Answer (score 1):

Just Modify your Code Little.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i){
myArray.get(i).position = random Position
if(myArray.get(i).position == allowed position){
    break;
   //Success!
}else{
  //re-attempt to change position until it meets criteria
   // countinue
  }
}
```

by writing break, your loop is terminated when you get your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean correctPosition=false;
for (int i = 0; !correctPosition; ++i){
    myArray.get(i).position = random Position
    if(myArray.get(i).position == 100){
       correctPosition=true;
       //Success!
   }else{
      //re-attempt to change position until it meets criteria
   }
}
```